# What does the set_handle_refresh() method on a Mechanize browser do?

Tags: python, mechanize

The Mechanize documentation mentions it briefly, but just sets it to False and nothing else. What are the parameters for and what does it actually do?

For example:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all about handling ["refresh" meta tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) behavior.

For example, if a page contains:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

the browser would refresh the page every 5 seconds.

And if you want to change the behavior, you would use `set_handle_refresh()`. E.g. if you want to turn refreshing off:

```
br.set_handle_refresh(False)
```

Hope that helps.